# How should I mention licenses in my iOS/Android game?

Tags: xamarin, admob, visual-studio-app-center

I use third party SDKs in my game. Google Admob to show ads in my game and Microsoft App Center Push so that the user can receive push notifications.

How should I mention Google Admob and Microsoft App Center in my game? Is it necessary to mention the licenses? Under what license can I use Google Admob And Microsoft App Center in my game?

[Admob](https://admob.google.com/home/)
[App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/)

Comment: Which tool did you use?Unity 3D or something other?

Comment: I use MonoGame.

Answer (score 0):

when the Game is starting call the admob and the AppCenter Init Function.
it's necessary to mention the Key so you can see use the services.
you need an AppCenter Key + Admob Key